# Reflection and method usages

Tags: c#, reflection

I have class A and class B in diferent assemblies, what I need to know is if there is a way to get the usages of the method A.foo() in class B's methods via reflection. I've read that maybe with IL?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Reflection does not include a decompiler, the kind of tool you need to see what members of another class are used by *code*.  Reflection only gives you declarations.  Decompilers are widely available, don't write your own.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this with reflection.  Reflection is based on the metadata of objects; the public APIs they expose.  Their internal implementations are not accessible at all through reflection.

Comment: @SaeedNeamati They don't use reflection (or at least not *just* reflection).  They're looking at the binary data itself and simply know how to interpret it (or try to anyway).  When using *just* reflection you're looking at a subset of the information those tools are using.

Comment: Reflector under the covers uses Mono.Cecil to read instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You can read method bodies using [`GetMethodBody()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getmethodbody.aspx) method. Then you're on your own to find usages. I'm creating a sample ...

This sample might help:

```
   Assembly assembly = Assembly
       .GetAssembly(typeof(B));

   List<Type> types = assembly.GetTypes().ToList();

   Type controller = types
   .Where(t => t.Name == "a-class-name")
   .Single();

   List<MethodInfo> methods = controller
   .GetMethods().ToList();

   MethodInfo method = methods
   .Where(m => m.Name == "a-method-name")
   .First();

   MethodBody body = method
   .GetMethodBody();

   // Search body.LocalVariables
```

I actually wrote an article about this [here](http://nefcanto.com/csharp-type-usage-statistics-via-reflection).

Comment: Saeed, can you give me copy of http://nefcanto.com/csharp-type-usage-statistics-via-reflection it is not working now

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using code analysis tools like Nitriq or NDepend? In NDepend's [Code Query over LINQ](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) it would be as easy as:

```
from t in Types 
where t.IsUsing ("ClassLibrary1.A.Foo()")
select new { t }
```

If you really need such information at runtime, there is [NDepend.API](http://www.ndepend.com/API/NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html) available, you can use CQLinq there. But if I were you, I would double reconsider why I want to find such information at runtime...